# Keep leading zeroes when converting string to integer

Tags: ruby

For no particular reason, I am trying to add a #reverse method to the Integer class:

```
class Integer
    def reverse
        self.to_s.reverse.to_i
    end
end

puts 1337.reverse # => 7331
puts 1000.reverse # => 1
```

This works fine except for numbers ending in a `0`, as shown when `1000.reverse` returns `1` rather than `0001`. Is there any way to keep leading zeroes when converting a string into an integer?

Comment: Sorry, what's the reason to keep the leading zeros?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Numbers don't have "leading zeroes". A particular string representation in a particular base may or may not have leading zeroes, but numbers most certainly don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no, you cant.

```
2.1.5 :001 > 0001
 => 1
```

0001 doesn't make sense at all as Integer. In the Integer world, 0001 is exactly as 1.

Moreover, the number of leading integer is generally irrelevant, unless you need to pad some integer for displaying, but in this case you are probably converting it into another kind of object (e.g a String).

If you want to keep the integer as `Fixnum` you will not be able to add leading zeros.

The real question is: why do you want/need leading zeros? You didn't provide such information in the question. There are probably better ways to achieve your result (such as wrapping the value into a decorator object if the goal is to properly format a result for display).

Comment: I need to keep leading zeroes because I was doing a bit of work on palindromic numbers, however if it's not possible to keep leading zeroes it will just be easier to use `to.s.reverse`. Thanks for actually trying to answer my question rather than questioning it :)

Answer (score 1):

Does `rjust` work for you?

```
1000.to_s.reverse.to_i.to_s.rjust(1000.to_s.size,'0') #=> "0001"
```

Comment: `rjust` is a String method. The result in your example is a `String` containing a numeric value, it's not a `Fixnum`.

Comment: When OP needs to keep leading zeros, it can only be a String, isn't?

Answer (score 0):

`self.to_s.to_i` does convert the integer to a string and this string "0001" to an integer value. Since leading zeros are not required for regular numbers they are dropped. In other words: Keeping leading zeros does not make sense for calculations, so they are dropped. Just ask yourself how the integer `1` would look like if leading zeros would be preserved, since it represents a 32 bit number. If you need the leading zeros, there is no way around a string.

BUT `10 + "0001".to_i` returns `11`, so you probably need to override the `+` method of the String class.

Comment: "so you probably need to override the + method of the String class." This is definitely a very bad, bad idea.

Comment: generally keeping leading zeros too, I guess it would be more easy to just do that in speacial case.